# All about Kreplach

Tags: sukkot, purim, yom-kippur, food

Many people eat Kreplach on Purim, Erev Yom Kippur, and Hoshanah Rabah. These 3 days are considered like hidden Yomim Tovim, as work is technically allowed. They are also days that we Klap. On Purim we Klap the Gragger. On Erev Yom Kippur we Klap Al Cheit. On Hoshanah Rabah we Klap Hoshanos. Most people use a outside dough with a chopped meat filling.

Question #1 - Does anyone know of any other reasons that we eat Kreplach on these days?

Question #2 - Does anyone have a Minhag to eat Kreplach on any other days?

Question #3 - Is there any other type of Kreplach that people eat?

Comment: Very Important question are you a fan of Rabbi Orlofsky he has a shir about this Topic on Torahanytime.com

Comment: To answer question 2: My wife & I like kreplach, so we eat them whenever we can.

Answer (score 5):

R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi gives a Kabbalistic reason for the custom (cited [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32573&st=&pgnum=327), note 11). In brief, it's based on the idea that lambs (and, I guess, meat in general) represents middos (emotions), while bread (or in this case, dough) represents daas (knowledge) - cf. the expression that "a child doesn't know how to say 'Father' or 'Mother' until he tastes grain" (Berachos 40a) - and this combination, middos "covered up" by daas, is associated with Yom Kippur.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer from [Vos iz neiaz](http://www.vosizneias.com/65084/2010/09/28/new-york-the-minhag-of-eating-kreplach-hoshana-rabbah)

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the reference is to this
[Rabbi Orlofsky Shiur](http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/David_Orlofsky/2008-09-21/Slichos_Night/Rabbi__Dovid_Orlofsky__Slichos_Night__2008-09-21.wmv)
Around 7 Minutes in