# Could a recipe achieve the force of halachah?

Tags: minhag, food

A binding custom may have the force of halachah, eg wearing a kippah in the everyday. Apart from festival dishes, though (where I can see a certain customary force to, say, cheesecake at Shavuot, and foods at Pesach beyond the clear halachah), are there any culinary recipes that could be considered binding customs? (I would add the tags gender and family, but they haven't been created.)

Comment: Menachos have a specific recipe

Comment: I was making chicken soup, and in a humorous vein thinking of it as compulsory, but of course it is actually not. But ancient would be fine too!

Comment: within families there are very strong customs, that would be shocking to go against.

Comment: do you mean ingredients (lo tevashel g'di is a strong "not in the recipe" instruction, and "no meat and fish" is a tradition which some have elevated) or the method of cooking (like chulent's having to be hot and heated from before shabbat, or the exact way of making matzah)?

Comment: @Heshy https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/seeking-old-jewish-recipes?r=SearchResults#comment53815_3273

Comment: @rosends no meat and fish is probably a good example, tho I had been thinking more of specific recipes, or methods I guess; or ways of preparing matzah would be good as long as we weren't talking about the unnegotiable 18 mins and the like. perhaps eating cold foods and not hot, on Shabbat, might engage the boundary I am wondering about, between law, custom and very strong and even "binding" custom... thanks

Comment: The recipe for keteret (incense) definitely rises to the level of halacha

Comment: @MarkJoseph Cholent in order to show that we can leave food to heat from before shabbos to show thast the Karaites were wrong about not leaving a flame on over shabbos. Gefilte fish in order to show that we are avoiding borer (removing the bones from the fish).

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone, food for thought... it makes me wonder what does make a custom binding... eg what happened that made this true of kippa wearing? (not the case I think forty years ago. ) charoset gets close to it I think. Interesting about hot food and gefilte fish.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45888/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3082/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14543/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13461/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97377/759